# How can I get session ID by process ID on Win XP

Tags: winapi, windows-xp

There is [`ProcessIdToSessionId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990(v=vs.85).aspx) function that works on Win Vista and later.

How can I get the session ID by the process ID on Windows XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN archive from archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110906025436/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382990(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Minimum supported client: Windows 2000 Professional

In case you mean older than Windows Vista,
Windows 2000/XP is no longer supported by Microsoft, therefore the old MSDN entry is missing

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What you are trying to say is that the function does exist in xp but MS have purged references to xp in MSDN.